# Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: 102: Session key invalid or no longer valid

Tags: facebook, session, facebook-graph-api, exception, key

Since yesterday (10 december) many of my apps have stopped working with executing facebook calls. For example calls for checking if the loggedin user has liked a page or getting all the albums of the loggedin user. I use the php sdk! 
With all my calls I receive :

*Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: 102: Session key invalid or no longer valid thrown in /xxxx/ on line yyy*

My facebook object is correct and I receive a valid user id with $facebook->getUser();

Example checking if a user is a fan:

```
$likes = $facebook->api('/'.$user.'/likes/154125631364512&access_token='.$facebook->getAccessToken());
```

Or example getting all the photo albums from the logged in user (fql):

```
$fql = "SELECT aid, object_id, cover_pid, name, size FROM album WHERE owner= '".$facebook->getUser()."'";
$userAlbums = $facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => $fql));
```

Or example, getting all the pictures from a album :

```
$params['fields'] = 'name,source,images,picture,height,width';
$params = http_build_query($params, null, '&');
$data['albumPhotos'] = $facebook->api("/album_object_id/photos?".$params);
```

All calls worked for weeks and suddenly are broke since the crash from facebook.
Anyone out there has any idea as to why these calls suddenly fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/181323008674971?browse=search_50c7385f82da62c58502145 you should update your PHP SDK but even doing this way, i'm still having problems; let's hope that they fix this annoying issue soon.

Comment: Thx for the answer. Since this morning a new update of the sdk solved my problems. Nonetheless I find it strange that the new update didn't solve my problems at first. I presume facebook worked hard yesterday to solve a lot of problems